# How to implementing two collection view inside of view controller?

Tags: iphone, swift, ios8, uicollectionview

Hi I am beginner in Swift programming language and I have problem to implementing two collection view inside of view controller, this is the link of my picture that I want to achieve:

[The picture I want to achieve](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/54006221/Screen%20Shot%202015-04-04%20at%2012.45.52%20AM.png)

is it possible? so far I have the codes that doesn't seems work:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate{

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

@IBOutlet weak var collectionViewTwo: UICollectionView!

var optionOne = ["Gulsah", "Hurrem", "Mihrimah", "Nilufer"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.resetFilterThumbnails()
    self.collectionView.delegate = self


}
//For the collectionView, number of filters in the section
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if (filters == true){
        //do all the stuff here for FILTER_CELL
        return self.filters.count}
    else{
        return self.optionOne.count}


}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("FILTER_CELL", forIndexPath: indexPath) as FilterThumbnailCell
    let cellTwo = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("FILTER_CELL_TWO", forIndexPath: indexPath) as FilterThumbnailCell
    var filterThumbnail = self.filterThumbnails[indexPath.row]
    println("filter cell two")

    if (indexPath.item == 0){
        //do all the stuff here for FILTER_CELL
        if filterThumbnail.filteredThumbnail != nil {
            cell.imageView.image = filterThumbnail.filteredThumbnail
        } else {
            cell.imageView.image = filterThumbnail.originalThumbnail
            //filterThumbnail is a class instance
            filterThumbnail.generateThumbnail({ (image) -> Void in
                if let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? FilterThumbnailCell {
                    cell.imageView.image = image
                }
            })
        }
        return cell

    }else{
        //FILTER_CELL_TWO
        var  button = cellTwo.viewWithTag(1) as UILabel

        button.text = optionOne[indexPath.row]
        cellTwo.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

        return cellTwo

    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very Possible.  You could do this in several ways.

**1:**

You could implement two contained view controllers.  This might be the cleanest since you could handle interaction in separate controllers. In this case you may need to also implement some delegate/protocols to pass information back to the parentViewController.

**2:**

You could create a separate datasource/delegate class to handle the associated functions for each view controller and assign them in viewDidLoad.  This case may also need to have delegates/protocols implemented to pass information from the collectionView dataSource/Delegate class.

Here is an example, taken from the Master-Detail starting class  Create your class like this (add conform to the UITableViewDelegate if needed):

```
import UIKit

class MyDataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {

    var objects = [AnyObject]()


    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return objects.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        let object = objects[indexPath.row] as NSDate
        cell.textLabel!.text = object.description
        return cell
    }
```

}

Then in your UIViewController you create a variable of type MyDataSource:

```
var dataSource1 = MyDataSource()
var dataSource2 = MyDataSource()
```

Inside of viewDidLoad you can assign the dataSource its objects and assign the datasource to the tableviews:

```
dataSource1.objects = objects1;
dataSource2.objects = objects2;

tableView1.dataSource = dataSource1
tableView2.dataSource = dataSource2
```

Now each of the tableviews will use a different instance of this DataSource, with its own set of model objects.  If you need to further customize you datasource (as it looks like you do) Simply create another data source class and assign it to the appropriate object.  If you conform to the delegate of the tableview inside these data source objects, you should implement a standard protocol for the data source, and conform to that protocol inside of your view controller:

Above the datasource object:

```
protocol DataSourceDelegate{ 
    func didSelectCellAtIndexPath(indexPath:NSIndexPath)
}
```

Inside of the data source object:

```
var dataSourceDelegate:DataSourceDelegate?
```

Inside of the view controller:

```
dataSource.dataSourceDelegate = self
```

Make sure to conform to the delegate in the class definition.  Then instantiate the method in the view controller:

```
func didSelectCellAtIndexPath(indexPath:NSIndexPath){
     // Your code here
}
```

Make sure to call the delegate inside the datasource

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    dataSourceDelegate?.didSelectCellAtIndexPath(indexPath)

}
```

To register cells, if you are using storyboard, just make sure that the cell identifiers are the correct ones, and you will not need to register anything else.  If not, you could register the cell inside the dataSource (probably a good idea, since it would keep all the info contained)

**3:**

You could use one viewController and differentiate between the cases by comparing the collectionView passed into the dataSource/Delegate functions to an outlet connected to the corresponding collectionViews in the view.  While this case will not need any delegates implemented, it will fill the viewController up with a lot of if/else statements, perhaps making the code more difficult to maintain/read.

Comment: Can you show me the code example for the number 2? Should I apply "registerClass(_ cellClass: AnyClass?, forCellWithReuseIdentifier identifier: String)" on viewDidLoad for number 2? @jbryson